# python - how to find up-to-date documentation?

Tags: python, documentation

I am new to Python, and keep running into the same problem: I can't find up-to-date examples of common Python solutions.

For example, googling "python html parser" gives me this as first result:

http://docs.python.org/2/library/htmlparser.html

The problem is that the code in this official doc is not working on Python 3.3.2 on windows, which is the [latest download](http://python.org/download/).

For example:

```
from HTMLParser import HTMLParser   # does NOT work for Python 3.3
```

is not working. Instead, one should use:

```
from html.parser import HTMLParser   # works for Python 3.3
```

This is just one example. Also a significant number of Stackoverflow Python codes answers do not work straight; for example:

```
print "text"    # does NOT work for Python 3.3
```

is now:

```
print ("text")  # works for Python 3.3
```

So my question is: how can I find up-to-date documentation and code examples that work for Python 3.3 on windows?

Comment: Be serious. All Python documentation is in a very good shape.

Comment: The URL you've mentioned has a prominent "2" in the URL. It also starts with `The HTMLParser module has been renamed to html.parser in Python 3.`. You're using python 3. What exactly is the confusion here?

Answer (score 2):

You tell Google the version of Python: `python 3.3 html parser`

First result: http://docs.python.org/3/library/html.parser.html

Note that a lot of support libraries don't fully support Python 3.x at this time. Which is why Python 2 still is the default for many projects.

If you plan to stay on 3.3, you may want to read "[What's New in Python](http://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/index.html)", especially "[What's New In Python 3.0](http://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.0.html)".

Comment: Thank you. Do you recommend using Python 2? I want to use it for data science (statistics).

Comment: If all your frameworks support Python 3, then use it. It's faster, the syntax has been cleaned up and you get better error messages. If you use Linux, then the easiest way is to install Python packages using the system's package manager. That will make sure the versions match and the result works. pip and easy_install are less reliable in this respect.

Answer (score 2):

If you see on the top left of the documentation page, there's `2.7.5`, the latest version for Python under version 3. You can click it and choose your version for the most up to date documentation.

On the example you gave, the top mentions that the module has been renamed in Python 3. If we go to a module that works in both 2 and 3, such as  [`itertools`](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/itertools.html), changing the number will redirect you to the updated documentation on itertools.

Answer (score 0):

here you can find Python 3 documentation: http://docs.python.org/3/